# When I paste multiline text to Google Spreadsheet, why the lines sometimes places one cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a multiline text, short example:

```
returned she; 
"for Mrs. Long has just been here, 
and she told me all about it."
Mr. Bennet made no answer.
```

When I paste it to Google Spreadsheet, I expect that every line place separate cell. And they do, in most of cases. But sometimes, like in example above, lines 2 and 3 places one cell. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of quote mark. If mask quote mark with `\` or `'`, all lines will place separate cells.